# Java ASM MethodVisitor's methods are not called by ClassVisitor

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

planned to instrumentate the methods on a java class with Java asm,

```
{

    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS | ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
    ClassVisitor cv = new LogMethodClassVisitor(cw, className);
    cr.accept(cv,  0);
    newClassByte = cw.toByteArray();

}
```

Below is the a derivative Class from ClassVisitor

```
public class LogMethodClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
    private String className;

    public LogMethodClassVisitor(ClassVisitor cv, String pClassName) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM4, cv);
        className = pClassName;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
                                     String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature,
                exceptions);

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("getParameter") && (mv != null)) {
            mv =  new PrintMessageMethodVisitor(mv, name, className);

        }

        return mv;
    }
}


public class PrintMessageMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

    String name;
    String classname;

    public PrintMessageMethodVisitor (MethodVisitor mv, String name, String classname)

    {
        super(ASM5, mv);
        this.name = name;
        this.classname = classname;
    }


    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
        {
            System.out.println ("###### entering visitCode ###### ");
        }
    }
```

only the constructor in PrintMessageMethodVisitor  from MethodVisitor is called. No other method such as visitCode is called.

I have tried different approaches from this forum such as,

```
1) use adviceadapter instead of methodVistor
2) cr.accept(cv,ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES) ;
```

None of them worked.

and I have those properties turned on,

```
                    <Can-Redefine-Classes>true</Can-Redefine-Classes>
                    <Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
                    <Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix>true</Can-Set-Native-Method-Prefix>
```

The above code is a typical Java asm instrumentation example, I must have missed trivial piece but I cannot figured it out.

Any clue? please help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake. the method is an abstract function without any code